# Open next month if selectable date falls in the next month

Tags: jquery

I have jQuery calendar. I have to make it so that only Monday or Tuesday etc are selectable depending on other variables. Now if today is 27 of April 2012 and the selectable days are Thursday with mindate set as 27th of April 2012 or the current date, The default month will still be April even if there are no selectable dates there.

How can I make it so that in those case the default month is the month which has selectable days in it.

I hope the figure will be helpful!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom function to set the `defaultDate`/`minDate`.  Here I have an array that defines valid days of the week. If the current date is not one, it move forward until it finds one.  You could customize something like this for your particular use:

```
var validDays = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0];

function firstDate() {
    var valDate = new Date();
    valDate.setDate(valDate.getDate() + 14);
    var day = valDate.getDay();
    var i = 0;
    while (validDays[day] != 1 && i < 7) {
        valDate.setDate(valDate.getDate() + 1);
        day = valDate.getDay();
        i++;
    }
    return valDate;
}

function validDate(date) {
    if (validDays[date.getDay()] == 1) {
        return [true, ""];
    } else {
        return [false, ""]
    }
}

$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: validDate,
        minDate: firstDate(),
        defaultDate: firstDate()
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/LgLr9/1/

Comment: Thanks it works, but I have already set the min date as +14 days. in this case what do I have to change to make it work

Comment: You need to add `valDate.setDate(valDate.getDate() + 14);` after the first line of `firstDate()`.  Edited above.